# Сделать кликабельным каждое слово в тексте

Tags: java, android, textview

Помогите пожалуйста, уже который день ломаю голову!
В выведенном из БД тексте нужно **каждое слово сделать кликабельным**, чтобы по клику на него выводился - в верхней части Activity перевод этого слова (через запрос к БД). Есть ли какие-то методы, как можно отслеживать клик на каждом слове внутри 1-го TextView?

1. У меня сначала была мысль кастомизировать ListView так, чтобы он
   выглядел, как обычный текст, и выводить в него дынные из БД через
   ArrayAdapter. Но, похоже, ListView не подойдет для такой цели.
2. Другой вариант - внутри вставленного из БД текста отслеживать
   нажатие на    каждом слове и производить по нему поиск перевода в
   БД.  Только как    это сделать? я новичок в
   андройд-программировании, пока недостаточно    опыта.
3. Программно в цикле создавать TextView, но как создать их столько, сколько слов в тексте (тексты в БД могут быть разные) и как на каждый из них вешать onClick?

[image: Вывод перевода при клике на слово]

Comment: Я нашла хорошее решение здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612652/select-a-word-on-a-tap-in-textview-edittext

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно реализовать при помощи ClickableSpan:

Создать строку, где кликабельные слова заключены в []:

```
String sentence = "[word1] [word2] [word3]";
```

Установить текст:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(addClickablePart(sentence), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Сам метод для создания кликабельных участков:

```
private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str) {
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);
        int idx1 = str.indexOf("[");
        int idx2;
        while (idx1 != -1) {
            idx2 = str.indexOf("]", idx1) + 1;
            final String clickString = str.substring(idx1, idx2);
            ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                    //TODO что необходимо c clickString
                }
            }, idx1, idx2, 0);
            idx1 = str.indexOf("[", idx2);
        }
        return ssb;
    }
```

Результат (показ Toast):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужен другой вывод, без скобок, задайте свои правила.

Comment: Хороший вариант, пробую реализовать, подскажите, пожалуйста, а как  внутри "public void onClick(View widget)" вывести id, позицию слова по клику, и можно ли [] скобки заменить на пробел, у меня каждое слово будет кликабельным

Comment: @soulfly84, ну к примеру, сделать запрос в базу, возвращающий что Вам необходимо по этому слову.

Comment: Спасибо, с id разобралась, а не знаете, как  [] скобки заменить на пробел? Чтобы по ним разделять слова, символ "\\s+" не работает

Comment: @soulfly84, посмотрите в сторону регулярных выражений.